# Recaptcha invalid-request-cookie

Tags: javascript, html, google-api, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to do `Recaptcha` in my page. I'm checking a demo with the `localhost`. But, I'm keep getting error as `invalid-request-cookie` always when checking. I'm following [Displaying recaptcha without plugin](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) and [Verifying recaptcha without plugin](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify).

Here is my code

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify">
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=my_public_key">
 <!-- I used my public key -->
</script>
<noscript>
 <iframe src="http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/noscript?k=my_public_key"
     height="300" width="500" frameborder="0"></iframe><br>
 <textarea name="recaptcha_challenge_field" rows="3" cols="40">
 </textarea>
 <input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response_field"
     value="manual_challenge">
</noscript>
<input type="hidden" name="privatekey" value="my_private_key">
<!-- I used my private key -->
<input type="submit" value="Ok"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

In google, I saw that, `invalid-request-cookie` means `The challenge parameter of the verify script was incorrect`. But It seems to be correct. Is it right or is there any other mistakes? Someone help please

Comment: I posted an answer - but if you are putting your private site key in the html markup, it will be visible to users viewing your page source.  It's generally not a good idea to put sensitive data in the markup - can you do this another way?

Answer (score 0):

After reading [this](http://logic.edchen.org/2013/11/resolving-recaptcha-error-invalid.html), I realized that the author of one of our forms was using a public key for a different domain we also have. So make sure you're using the correct public key.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Google recaptcha in an ASP.Net environment.  Here is my code snippet:

in head tag:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

HTML:

```
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="My***PUBLIC***SiteKeyBlahBlah"></div>
```

That's it!  Google handles the rest of the magic.  You can check the length of the grecaptcha.getResponse() function's return variable to see if the user clicked it.  For example:

```
if (grecaptcha.getResponse().length == 0)
     //They didn't do it
else
     //They either did it or spoofed your page with some bogus HTML to make it look like they did - they can do this by editing the source of the page and inserting text in a certain spot.  View your page source after loading in a browser to see what I mean.
```

To verify that they didn't just enter random text - and that the value of grecaptcha.getResponse() is a valid response from Google, just call their web service with your site key - and the response, itself.  I'm doing it from the code-behind with C# like so:

```
WebRequest CheckCaptcha;
            CheckCaptcha = WebRequest.Create(String.Format([Google's Web Service URL],
                                            [Your ***Private*** Site Key],
                                            [The value of grecaptcha.getResponse()],
                                            [IP address]));
            Stream strm = CheckCaptcha.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strm);
            string everything = sr.ReadToEnd();

            JavaScriptSerializer JS = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            CaptchaResponse GoogleResponse = JS.Deserialize<CaptchaResponse>(everything);
```

Next, to evaluate Google's response:

```
if (GoogleResponse.success.ToUpper() != "TRUE")
    //Invalid - they are up to no good! 
else
    //Valid - you're good to go!
```

Calling their web service is probably slightly different if you're doing it from the client side, but it's the same principle.  I hope this helps.